# trying to upgrade from 15.10 to 16.04 but I got error

Tags: apt, upgrade, 16.04, 15.10, aptitude

I tried to do it but I got these massages which are [image]

and also 
[image]

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install -f` as suggested?

Comment: again I got lasted eror